# how to convert one object into another using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, mapper, c#-10.0

I want to map an object that I have inside another using automapper,

This is my response class, where I have the country object inside it and I want to map it, as I show you in the following image,

```
public class AxisResponseDto
{
    #region Properties
    public int AxisId { get; set; }
    public string? AxisName { get; set; }
    public CountryResponseDto? Country { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

and this is my response of my country object which is what i want it to become,

```
public class CountryResponseDto
{
    #region Properties
    public short CountryId { get; set; }
    public string? CountryName { get; set; }
    public string? AreaCode { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

this is the answer i hope

```
{
   axisId: 1,
   axisName: 'Santo Domingo',
   cuntry: {
    countryId: 1
    countryName: 'Republica Dominicana'
    countryId: '1'
    }
}
```

This is my query to get my axis object

```
    public async Task<BaseResponse<GetAxisByIdResponseDto>> Handle(GetAxisByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        BaseResponse<GetAxisByIdResponseDto> response = new BaseResponse<GetAxisByIdResponseDto>();

        try
        {
            Axis axis = await _axisRepository.FindAxisId(request.AxisId);

            if (axis is null)
            {
                response.IsSuccess = false;
                response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_QUERY_EMPTY;
                return response;
            }

            response.IsSuccess = true;
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetAxisByIdResponseDto>(axis);
            response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_QUERY;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_EXCEPTION;
            WatchLogger.Log(ex.Message);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

This is my axis class

```
public class Axis
{
    #region Properties
    public int AxisId { get; set; }
    public string? AxisName { get; set; }
    public short CountryId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is my GetAxisByIdResponseDto class

```
public class GetAxisByIdResponseDto
{
    #region Properties
    public int AxisId { get; set; }
    public string? AxisName { get; set; }
    public CountryResponseDto? Country { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

what I want is that when I do a find of the axis object by id, convert the country object that has the response, to the class that I commented before, I don't know how to do this part since I'm new using mapper with #,

I would appreciate the help

Stay tuned to your comments

Comment: good start point for you https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

Comment: With that documentation I have made the simple mappings, but these that are complex I have not been able to do, that is why I am seeing if you can help me @VivekNuna

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to map anything. If u already found the Axis object and it has the Country object inside, you can just access it or return it without any mapping taking place

Comment: I understand that if I need to do the mapping because I need the CountryId and the CountryName inside the country object that has the axis object @R44

Comment: It is not auto-mapping. You search one object based on the other, and then fill in rest of the field values. Implement it using simple old-fashion methods.

Comment: I think you should reformulate your question, it is not clear to me what are u trying to achieve. Are u getting the Country as a Json maybe? and that is what u want to map to your DTO? I'm guessing

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the following, when I search for the axis object, which has the country object inside, I want it to get that complete object with the properties of the country object, that's what I want @R44

Comment: Can you include some example code of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: edit my question with the answer i expect @Orion

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html nested mapping works ok. Just CreateMap for classes

Comment: Please show us the implementation for `GetAxisByIdResponseDto` and `Axis` classes. Thanks.

Comment: I just edited my question with the requested @YongShun

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, `Axis` instance with providing the `CountryId` will not convert the id to `Country`. Either that your `Axis` instance should include with `Country` instance (Entity Framework include related entity) or you need to implement the [custom value resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) to query the `Country` from DB according to the source's `CountryId`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any AutoMapping for this. Because your `AxisResponseDto` already includes `CountryResponseDto`.

If you are getting the data from database, then you need to do an Eager Loading with `Include()` keyword, so that it will fetch both table data.

Comment: I can't use the include because I'm using dapper with stored procedures and that's why I want to know how I map another object inside another because with the countryid that is inside the axisId I have to perform a search, for what you recommend it wouldn't work for me @Ajay

Comment: What ORM are you using? Is the data coming from database via stored procedure?

Comment: Exactly, the data comes from a database using dapper c# @Ajay Managaon

Comment: Can you share dapper query?

Comment: I just shared my code of how I get my axis object, I edited my question @Ajay

Comment: Sir, Why are you returning "BaseResponse<GetAxisByIdResponseDto>" ? when you want "AxisResponseDto" as the output? It should be "BaseResponse<AxisResponseDto>".